# In MIPS Assembly language, when do you know when to use syscall?

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls, qtspim

I am not looking for a subjective answer, but rather a concrete one.
I thought you were supposed to use syscall when you finish writing an instruction.

However, the following code when put into QTSpim gives me the error:  "Unknown System Call: 115".

```
.text
main:
li $v0, 12
syscall

add $s0, $v0, $0
syscall

move $a0, $s0
li $v0, 11
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

.data
```

After looking into it a little deeper, I discover that this works:

```
.text
main:
li $v0, 12
syscall

add $s0, $v0, $0
move $a0, $s0
li $v0, 11
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

.data
```

So why is this so, and when are you supposed to use syscall so it works without errors?

Comment: You have asked two questions. You use a syscall when it will achieve what you want, without having to write your own implementation, or when you are restricted from doing so (for example, accessing the hardware). You call it without errors by passing valid register arguments, as documented.

Comment: http://students.cs.tamu.edu/tanzir/csce350/reference/syscalls.html

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though. Why does the first one give me an error and the second one doesn't? And @Ped7g I have that already lol. That's how I learned mips.

Comment: I don't have qtspim, but you have. Step over the first code instruction by instruction, and watch how `v0` becomes 115 somewhere, then next `syscall` will fail (or the v0 will be legal, but some other argument will be not). See which `syscall` fails, then check ahead of it the values in registers => crosscheck that against that documentation.

Comment: Actually I bothered now to read the page I posted. So in your first code you do `syscall, v0=12` ("read character"), which wait for user input of single character. You did hit "s". The syscall returned value `115` (value of ASCII character `'s'`) in `v0`. The next `syscall` fails, because `115` is unknown service for it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Ped7g! 115 is an unknown service, but if it was a value from 1-12 it would be a known service per the chart.